# Faster way of detecting multiple pixels and clicking them in parallel in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, click, pyautogui, pypy

I'd like to code a bot, that is able to play a game, which is called "piano Tiles". Basically there are four vertical lanes, and there are black tiles falling down in each lane. The player needs to click them before they reach the End of the screen. Its getting faster while playing.

My goal is to get the highest score possible. The world record is currently at 17 clicks/second(tiles/second). I am not able to get any higher than 15 clicks/second but i am just not able to tell where i slow my script down.

My first approach was to check one single pixel/lane with pyautogui.pixel(x,y) and if its rgb value == the color of the tile - click on that position. Score with that variant ~10 clicks/second.

After that i calculated an offset to keep on with the acceleration, basically i added an increasing number to the y position of that click, which left me at arround 12 clicks/second.

I recorded it and watched it fail frame by frame. What happend is, that eventually the game got so fast that the script for an example is not able to detect pixel in "lane 1" while click happens in "lane 4"

The solution, i came up with, is multiprocessing and pypy.

```
    import pyautogui
    import multiprocessing
    import time


    time.sleep(2)
    print("READYprint")



    def Lane1():
        a = 0
        b = 0
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
        while True:

            if pyautogui.pixel(800, 520) [0] == 0:
                pyautogui.click(x=800, y=520 + b)
                
                a = a + 1
                b = a // 15
            
            
                

    def Lane2():
        a = 0
        b = 0
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
        while True:

            if pyautogui.pixel(902, 520) [0] == 0:
                pyautogui.click(x=902, y=520 + b)
                
                a = a + 1
                b = a // 15
            
                

    def Lane3():
        a = 0
        b = 0
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
        while True:

            if pyautogui.pixel(1033, 520) [0] == 0:
                pyautogui.click(x=1033, y=520 + b)
                
                a = a + 1
                b = a // 15
            
                

    def Lane4():
        a = 0
        b = 0
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
        while True:

            if pyautogui.pixel(1134, 520) [0] == 0:
                pyautogui.click(x=1134, y=520 + b)
                
                a = a + 1
                b = a // 15
            
                

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane1)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane2)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane3)
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane4)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        p1.start()
        p2.start()
        p3.start()
        p4.start()
```

i also did run a test, to benchmark the performance of the script.

```
import time
import pyautogui

start_time = time.time()


def test():
    a = 0
    b = 0
    pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
    while a < 100:
     
        if pyautogui.pixel(970, 208) [0] == 255:
        
            pyautogui.click(x=970, y=208 + b)
            a = a + 1
            b = a // 15


test()

    
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Output: --- 1.7149109840393066 seconds ---, which is for 100 times "get rgb value + click, if its  white."

I have no idea why the bot is that "slow" then. When it fails its far away from that 0,017... seconds/checked_click. Could the reason for this be the multiprocessing? While it did get a bit faster, it should have been a lot faster. I also did run it without pypy. Without the pypy JIT its ~13 clicks/second.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question but it might be faster to get a screenshot for all four lanes at once. `pyautogui.pixel()` [combines](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#pixel-matching) the screenshot and getpixel functions. So your code gets a screenshot individually for each lane. A faster way might be to do this:

```
xlocations= [800,902,1033,1134]
yloc=520
while True:
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    for xloc in xlocations: 
       if im.getpixel((xloc, yloc)) [0] == 0:
          pyautogui.click(x=xloc, y=yloc+ b)
          a = a + 1
          b = a // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

The "final" solution i came up with was the following:

```
import time
import win32api, win32con, win32ui
import multiprocessing

time.sleep(1)
print("RDY")

def Lane1():

    
    window_name = "App Player" 
    wd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    

    while True:
        dc = wd.GetWindowDC()
        try:

             
            j = dc.GetPixel (35,230)  
            
            if j == 0:
                
                win32api.SetCursorPos((35, 230))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            dc.DeleteDC()

        except win32ui.error:
            print("we got an error 1")
            continue

def Lane2():

    
    window_name = "App Player" 
    wd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
     

    while True:
        dc = wd.GetWindowDC()

        try:

            
            j = dc.GetPixel (60,240)  
            
            if j == 0:
                
                win32api.SetCursorPos((60, 240))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            dc.DeleteDC()

        except win32ui.error:
            print("we got an error 2")
            continue

def Lane3():

    
    window_name = "App Player" 
    wd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    
    while True:
        dc = wd.GetWindowDC()

        try:

            
            j = dc.GetPixel (120,250)  
            
            if j == 0:
                
                win32api.SetCursorPos((120, 250))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            dc.DeleteDC()

        except win32ui.error:
            print("we got an error 3")
            continue

def Lane4():

    
    window_name = "App Player" 
    wd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
    

    while True:
        dc = wd.GetWindowDC()
         

        try:

            
            j = dc.GetPixel (180,260)  
            
            if j == 0:
                
                win32api.SetCursorPos((180, 260))
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            dc.DeleteDC()

        except win32ui.error:
            print("we got an error 4")
            continue
        

        




p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane1)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane2)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane3)
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Lane4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()
```

i checked pixels on different y positions to not have this race condition between the different processes, which did lead to missklicks. Also it helped a lot to keep the game window as small as possible because emulators tend to be laggy.

With this version of the bot the score is about 22 clicks/second.